"detail": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
I was trying to add rows to spreadsheet of a sheety project with the following code:
import requests
import json
class FlightData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_id = "nMiV3AM7RZvMQGBC9d5r8qwkjikmIBzh"
        self.api_secret = "KtUx9vmoOLYFiwEL"
        self.token = " RpbiYmNrhmP04WHmcAUxCFISMRBC"
   
        def get_token(self):
        "To get Token when it is invalid"
        endpoint = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token"
        parameter = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', "client_id": self.api_id, "client_secret": self.api_secret}
        header = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        response = requests.post(url=endpoint, data=parameter, headers=header)
        response_data = response.text
        res = json.loads(response_data)
        print(res)
        self.token = res['access_token']


   def get_iata_code(self):
        endpoint = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/cities"
        parameter = {"keyword": "PAR", 'max': 10}
        header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {self.token}"}
        response = requests.get(url=endpoint, params=parameter, headers=header)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        data1 = []
        for i in range(0, len(data['data'])):
            name = data["data"][i]["name"]
            state_code = data["data"][i]["address"]["stateCode"]
            dict1 = {"name": name, "stateCode": state_code}
            data1.append(dict1)
        return data1


def iata_code_adder(info):
    list1 = info
    endpoint = "https://api.sheety.co/fd65cc87954706f35e0debbd37a8d429/flightDeals/prices"
    print(type(info))
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        body = {"price": {"name": list1[i]["name"], "stateCode": list1[i]["stateCode"]}}
        response = requests.post(url=endpoint, json=body)
        print(response.text)
fd = FlightData()
data = fd.get_iata_code()
iata_code_adder(data)

The above code is giving me an error. What does this mean, and how can I resolve it?
"errors": [
  {
    "detail": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
  }]

I was expecting to add rows containing state name and state code but I am getting this error continuosly "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
